# Can't get HTML5 Canvas to Work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning HTML5 and can't get anything to appear on the screen. It just comes up totally white. All of the code is below.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="canvas.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<section id="main">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
        Get Chrome
    </canvas>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
 function doFirst(){
var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas = x.getContext('2d');

canvas.shadowOffsetX = 4;
canvas.shadowOffsetY = 4;
canvas.shadowBlur = 6;
canvas.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,255,.5)';

canvas.font="36px Tahoma";
canvas.textAlign="end";
canvas.strokeText("omgjj", 300, 500);
 }
 window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Comment: Btw, you forgot to declare `canvas`. (`var canvas = ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Y coordinate is off the canvas. Change this:

```
canvas.strokeText("omgjj", 300, 500);
```

To this:

```
canvas.strokeText("omgjj", 300, 200);
```

And your text will appear:
[image: A screenshot of the canvas, displaying the text 'omgjj', stroked, with a bluish drop shadow]

Comment: THANK YOU! I didn't notice that